# Overhead of Java assert call

Tags: java, testing, jvm, assert

How is it that a Java `assert` call to verify the value of a variable can be a no-op?  Wouldn't operations be required to compare the expected value to the actual value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a no-op. A system property determines whether assertions are enabled or disabled. The `assert` statement gets compiled into an if statement which checks if assertions are enabled then executes the actual assertion check.

Check out the oracle [doc](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/assertions-139853.html) on assertions which covers how it could be accomplished before the keyword (1.3) and how the keyword works in 1.4+.